# Visual Studio Tips on getting headers that are used in a given project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

I have added all the header files from library in path how to get the headers that are only needed for the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a compiler option that will produce a list of included files for a compilation unit in your Build Output window.

In the property page for the compilation unit, under the C/C++ Advanced section, there's an option called "Show Includes". Turn that on and recompile. You can probably do this on the project level as well, but I suggest you do it per compilation unit (.cpp) one by one.